# Finding buttons in Instagram using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working with selenium using python and I have problems with finding correnct x.path selector in instagram. There are svg, a class ,span class etc. when I open inspect tab. How can I identify correct x.path selector in a website. Is there a formula to do it. I wanted to click profile button and I failed many times.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend referring to the following resource to gain insights into the topic of XPath.
https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/

I have attempted to automate the process involving the need to click on the profile button as per your requirements. Here is the Python code that I have implemented for this purpose:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Enter your email or Phonenumber")
select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")
select.send_keys("Enter your password")
select.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(6)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/span/div/a/div").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

I have explored two XPath expressions derived from distinct HTML tags: one associated with the 'div' and another with the 'span'. The XPath corresponding to the 'div' tag functions perfectly, while the one associated with the 'span' encounters an issue due to the profile being nested within a [container structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XoXw.png). Therefore, for an effective means of pressing the profile button, it is advisable to use the XPath derived from the 'div' tag, as it addresses the need to click on the encompassing container.

This is the XPath derived from the div tag:

> /html/body/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0WSs.png)/div/div/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0WSs.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/)/div[1](https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/)/div[1](https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/)/div/div/div/div/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0WSs.png)/div[8]/div/span/div/a/div

This is the XPath derived from the span tag:

> //span[text()='Profile']